# Another Little Number riddle!

Tags: lateral-thinking

**Please try your best to solve the puzzle below GOOD LUCK!!**

```
THE NUMBERS 0-10 and 99 CAN BE CATEGORIZED 
INTO THESE 4 CATEGORIES IF ANY OF 
THESE NUMBERS ARE NOT FOUND 
IN ANY OF THE CATEGORIES 
THEY DON’T BELONG THERE! THE 
NAMES OF THE CATEGORIES ARE 
SIGNIFICANT! AND THERE IS A
COMMON ‘THEME NUMBER’ WHICH
APPLIES TO ALL FOUR OF THEM!
_____

CATEGORY 0

2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,99

CATEGORY ANTI-0

0,1,10

CATEGORY 1

3,4,5,6,7,8,9

CATEGORY ANTI-1

0,1,2,10,99
______

Can you explain the categorization 
of these numbers?
```

Comment: Is the current formatting of this puzzle (making it up as code etc.) necessary for the solution?

Comment: -1 for editing the question to make a valid answer wrong, because it found a logical explanation you hadn't thought of.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> In category 0 the numbers are those when 0 is added to the right of them, make numbers ending with -TY like TWENTY, THIRTY and so on.

> In category anti-0 this is not the case

> In category 1 numbers are those when 1 is added to the left of them make a number ending with -TEEN.

> In category anti-1 this is not the case

> I believe the common number is 10 since it is the litmus test via multiplying or adding to a number to figure out if a number fits in a category or not…

Comment: Nice one good work!!!

Answer (score 5):

> Category Anti-0 and Anti-1 are valid numbers in binary and ternary format.
>  Then Category Anti-n would be all valid numbers in base-(n+1).

> Not sure about the common theme.